# Find 2nd most significant digit

Tags: node.js

I have a scenario where I need to compare two numbers and determine if there is a difference in the 2nd most significant digit. These numbers are decimal with 10 places.

```
0.0000098765
0.0000098766
// Change = false

0.0000098765
0.0000099765
// Change = true

0.0000098765
0.0000198765
// Change = true
```

Looking at my examples above and rethinking the question I would want to know when either the 2nd or 1st significant digits change.

I know how to round however I have no idea how to approach this problem.

```
function significantDigitChange(number1, number2) {
  var shift1 = number1 * Math.pow(10,10);
  var shift2 = number2 * Math.pow(10,10);

  if ( shift1.toString().slice(0,2) != shift2.toString().slice(0,2) ) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you know in advance which digits you care about?  Like if the number is 0.35, is it still the 3 digit (2nd from the right) that you care about?  Or, can you say in advance that it's the 9th digit right of the decimal that you care about, no matter what value the number has?  What if you're comparing 0.35 to 0.34?  What if you're comparing 0.0000000035 to 0.0000000034?

Comment: Unfortunately the numbers to be compared can be anywhere in the precision range. As per your example above I could be comparing 0.35 vs 0.34 in one instance and later 0.0000000035 vs 0.0000000034

Comment: You did not answer any of my questions. Can't help without answers to clarify the problem.  Please reread exactly what I asked and provide answers.  Also, what to do when comparing different length like 0.351 vs. 0.350000001.  Your problem is simply not described well enough to understand.

Comment: Is this taking into account rounding? For example, what’s the result between 0.129 and 0.130?

Comment: No rounding. 0.129 vs 0.130 should indicated a change and return true as the 2nd significant digit has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Make a function to truncate a (positive) number to some significant digits:

```
function toPrecision(n, precision) {
    var scale = 10 ** (Math.floor(Math.log10(n)) - precision + 1);

    return Math.trunc(n / scale) * scale;
}
```

Use it on both values and compare for equality:

```
function significantDigitChange(n1, n2) {
    return toPrecision(n1, 2) !== toPrecision(n2, 2);
}
```